# Why is the first condition of "else if" statement always false?

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement, logic

I am assuming this is some logic error I am overlooking and am hoping someone can enlighten me on the mechanics of Java in this scenario. The first condition in the if else statements (id == R.id.checkbox1) are highlighted by Android Studio as being always false, why?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    int id = view.getId();
    int page = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    boolean cBoxChecked = false;

    switch(page) {
        case 0: case 1: case 3: case 4: case 6: case 10:
            if(id == R.id.button2)
                answersStatus.set(page, true);
            else
                answersStatus.set(page, false);
        case 2:
            if(id == R.id.button1)
                answersStatus.set(page, true);
            else
                answersStatus.set(page, false);
        case 5: case 7:
            if(id == R.id.checkbox1 || id == R.id.checkbox4 && cBoxChecked)
                cBoxChecked = true;
                  //____________________
            else if(id == R.id.checkbox1 || id == R.id.checkbox4 && !cBoxChecked)
                  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                answersStatus.set(page, true);
            else
                answersStatus.set(page, false);
        case 8:
            if(id == R.id.checkbox1 || id == R.id.checkbox5 && cBoxChecked)
                cBoxChecked = true;
                  //____________________
            else if(id == R.id.checkbox1 || id == R.id.checkbox5 && !cBoxChecked)
                  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                answersStatus.set(page, true);
            else
                answersStatus.set(page, false);
        case 9:

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it because you have exactly the same conditions in if and else if statements?

Comment: So should I omit the first two conditions in the else if statement and simply write: "else if(!cBoxChecked)" ?

Comment: You're missing `break` statements, by the way.

Comment: Ha yeah just noticed it a couple of minutes ago, thanks.

Comment: You do whatever your logic requires. But if you write if(a){}else if(a), then else if clause will never get executed, since if a is true else doesn't compute. If a is false, it doesn't compute either.

Comment: @VictorHavin missed the part about the higher precedence of &&, it makes sense now

Comment: I did not say anything about higher precedence of &&. It doesn't matter in this case. What matters is the redundant else if Clause.But, if I am not mistaken, you already have it resolved.

Comment: @VictorHavin - The conditions for `if` and `else if` are not the same.  Look closely.  There is a `!` on the `cBoxChecked` term.

Comment: Darn! I will need a better pair of glasses. Then yes, the && precedence is really important here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` has more priority then `||`

So when you are writing below statement:

```
if(id == R.id.checkbox1 || id == R.id.checkbox4 && cBoxChecked)
```

It will check either for

```
id == R.id.checkbox1
```

or

```
id == R.id.checkbox4 && cBoxChecked
```

Now the other else if statement says:

```
else if(id == R.id.checkbox1 || id == R.id.checkbox4 && !cBoxChecked)
```

which will again be split into

```
id == R.id.checkbox1
```

or

```
id == R.id.checkbox4 && !cBoxChecked
```

As the first statement "`id == R.id.checkbox1`" is same and whenever it will be true, the statements inside if will be called instead of else if.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Knew it had to be a logic error, thank you for the breakdown!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one of the code snippets.

```
if(id == R.id.checkbox1 || id == R.id.checkbox4 && cBoxChecked)
    cBoxChecked = true;
else if(id == R.id.checkbox1 || id == R.id.checkbox4 && !cBoxChecked)
    answersStatus.set(page, true);
else
    answersStatus.set(page, false);
```

The "then" statement of the first `if` will be executed when *EITHER* `id == R.id.checkbox1` is true *OR* when `id == R.id.checkbox4 && cBoxChecked` is true.

So if you get to the `else if`, that means that `id == R.id.checkbox1` *CANNOT BE* true.  That is what the compiler is saying.

In Java (and in most / all other programming languages I have encountered) precedence of `&&` is higher than `||`.

Maybe you meant to write this:

```
if ((id == R.id.checkbox1 || id == R.id.checkbox4) && cBoxChecked)
    cBoxChecked = true;
else if ((id == R.id.checkbox1 || id == R.id.checkbox4) && !cBoxChecked)
    answersStatus.set(page, true);
else
    answersStatus.set(page, false);
```

Comment: Yep that was it, gave it to Aman because he pointed it out first. Thank you for the correction, that is what I meant it to be.

Comment: Doesn't matter. In your code else if clause is redundant because it has the same condition as if. This means else if clause will never get executed (see my comment in the original question).

Comment: See my comment on your comment.